# Is there a way to keep column height unaffected in HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an `HTML` table with two columns with some text in them. Clicking a link on the right column renders some content dynamically that increases the column length to more than double. This in-turn causes the text on the left column to expand and look ugly. Is there a way to keep the text on the left column in-tact despite the increased right column length?

Comment: Please show an example of your code for this.

Comment: You can fix the width of the left column like `style="width:100px"`